# Conversion tools database structure (oracle, mysql,postgreSQl..) to HSQLDB or H2

Tags: oracle, postgresql, testing, hsqldb, in-memory

I want to use HsqlDB or H2 to make tests with an in-memory database. I have databases in production with Oracle and postgreSQL. So I want to know if there are tools that allow converting an oracle, postgreSQL... database structure  to a hSQLDB or H2 schema.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DdlUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/).

Quoted from that site

> DdlUtils can generate a DDL file for an existing database.
>   These are XML files that contain the definition of a database schema, e.g. tables and columns.
>   These files can be fed into DdlUtils via its Ant task or programmatically
>   in order to create the corresponding database or alter it so that it corresponds to the DDL

You might encounter difficulties in the first run, if the reverse engineering fails. Anyway, somehow you can manage to get a logical data model, and you can use this both for production and testing.

Comment: I don't understand how to use it and can't download it.

Comment: @BornToCode Please consult that documentation; if problems persist, please post a separate question, including all the things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out [RazorSQL](http://razorsql.com) can convert between PostgreSQL, Oracle and HSQL, but I couldn't get it to produce valid HSQLDB files from PostgreSQL..

Disclaimer: it's a commercial product with a 30day trial period, and I'm not affiliated in any way..